# Detecting text selection in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextarea, caret

I have a JTextArea and am deteching if any text is selection, if none is then two of the menu items are grayed out. The problem I have is, when I compile and open the application I have to click on the JTextArea first and then then the menu items are greyed out, if I don't they aren't even if no text is selected. I am using the following caret listener.

```
    textArea.addCaretListener(new CaretListener() {

        @Override
        public void caretUpdate(CaretEvent arg0) {
            int dot = arg0.getDot();
            int mark = arg0.getMark();
            if (dot == mark) {

                copy2.setEnabled(false);
                cut1.setEnabled(false);
            }
            else{
                cut1.setEnabled(true);
                copy2.setEnabled(true);
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should `setEnabled(false)` on each of these menu items when you create them.

Comment: This works, is there a better way? (It seems kind of tacky to me, it might just be me though).

Comment: @Jeff - think of it this way: selection is a positive action that enables the menu items. When you start the app, no selection has taken place yet, so those items should be at their default state. Which is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You can define enable/disable logic for cut/copy menu items in a separate function, and call that function while initializing GUI, and also that function will be called on CaretUpdate (or better be MouseReleased) event.

```
JTextArea textArea;
......
........
public void init()
{   
    ......
    ........
    textArea=new JTextArea();
    // add textArea to parent container
    // now initialize menu items state
    setEditingMenuItemsState();
    textArea.addCaretListener(new CaretListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void caretUpdate(CaretEvent arg0)
        {
            setEditingMenuItemsState();
        }
    });
    ......
    ........
}

public void setEditingMenuItemsState()
{
    String selectedText;

    if ( textArea == null ) selectedText = null;

    if ( selectedText == null || selectedText.isEmpty() )
    {
        copy2.setEnabled(false);
        cut1.setEnabled(false);
    }

    else
    {
        cut1.setEnabled(true);
        copy2.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use 
JtextField.setHighlighter(null);